# How to write a matrix output with a string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I am not sure how to search for what I am trying to achieve.

Say I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
x = [1;2;3];
```

How do I output something like:

```
First row = 1
Second row  = 2
Third row = 3
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can always use `fprintf`, but it will not count the row numbers in english :)

```
fprintf('row value %d\n', x)

row value 1
row value 2
row value 3
```

You can also add individual row text, if you insist:

```
% convert your x vector to a cell matrix
Cx = mat2cell(x, ones(size(x)));

% define individual row texts in a cell matrix
str = {'First  row'; 'Second row'; 'Third  row'};

% print both using cellfun
cellfun(@(s,v)fprintf('%s %d\n', s, v), str, Cx);

First  row 1
Second row 2
Third  row 3
```

Comment: Maybe `%d` instead of `%f` would be better in that case.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! Just wondering is it also possible to just pick one of the numbers? Let's say i just want the second number (2) and printout row value 2

Comment: @jonprasetyo Use normal vector indexing - `fprintf('%d\n', x(2))`